# wxPython MVC working with GUI

Tags: python, model-view-controller, wxpython, observer-pattern

I have a working program in 1 class. I wish to convert it to MVC pattern.

I've implemented observer design as [shown here](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5117) and i opened 3 `.py` files for Model, View and Controller.
I'm having trouble understanding what goes where.

For example:
this code in the original class

```
    helpMenu = wx.Menu()
    helpMenu.Append(ID_ABOUT, "&About", "Display info")

    self.Bind(event=wx.EVT_MENU, handler=self.OnHelpAbout, id=ID_ABOUT)
```

...

```
def OnHelpAbout(self,e):
    title = self.GetTitle()
    d = wx.MessageDialog(self, "About " + title, title, wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.OK)
    d.ShowModal()
    d.Destroy()
```

This menu code lines should be in the View, and the function `OnHelpAbout` should be implemented in the Controler. But how do I call it? should I have an instance of the Controller in the View? Where do I sign for the observer?
Also, if this function set a dialog = making changes in the view How do I do that? If I understood correctly I need to call another function in the View and put the code there?

I guess what i'm missing is a basic template to work with. I haven't found any source that explains how to do it with GUI & GUI Events.

Comment: The GUI code is typically the "View". The event handlers will just call stuff that's in the "Controller". The Model is harder to define unless you have a database or are using something like XRC.

Comment: I know that. The question is set because in my case OnHelpAbout which is controller function also need to change the view. So I asked how do i do that. Also, how do i set the events in the controler. Should I have an instance of the controller in the GUI?

Comment: Yeah, that gets messy. I don't follow the rules rigidly because I don't think they work that well with desktop GUI libraries. However, you could use pubsub to send a message to the view from the controller telling it to update. As for your second question, I would just import the controller module(s) into your GUI code and call them appropriately: `controller.DoSomething()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MVC entry in the wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController) gives a good insight how the spearation of concerns could look like. The first (newer) example leverages `pypubsub`, the older example at the bottom deals with `wx.Events` alone.

While it may or may not conform to the strict MVC paradigma, it shows beautifully how the model is separated form view and controller.

In your example the creation of the menu (the first two lines) would go into the view. The controller would hold the event method (`OnHelpAbout`) and do the binding on the menu item. For the model your example would have no code. The frame title could be kept in the controller and put into the frame on object creation/after creation.

**UPDATE/EDIT1**

This is no exact science and can get messy as already pointed out. How about the following:

view.py

```
class myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(…
        # code for menu creation goes here
        self.helpmenu = …
```

controller.py

```
from view import myframe

class mycontroller(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.title = 'mytitle'
        self.frame = myframe(…
        self.frame.SetTitle(self.title)

        self.frame.helpmenu.Bind(…, handler=self.OnHelpAbout, …)

        self.frame.Show()

    def OnHelpAbout(self, evt):
        title = self.title
        # show message dialog
        …

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(…
    ctrler = mycontroller(app)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Wake me if you manage to find a "pure" solution …

Comment: I read the examples there before i opened this question... it didn't answer my question. there are no GUI events there. I think you didn't understand my question. In your answer you wrote what goes where. That information I already know and I wrote it in my question. What I don't know is how to do the calls. where should I have instances of controller? where should I have instance of View? How do i change the OnHelpAbout to qualify as MVC pattern as this function does GUI commands but it should be in the controller.